# return rvalue of temporary as value

Tags: c++, rvalue, rvo

So, I have the following class:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Bar &&bar() {
        return std::move(_bar);
    }
private:
    Bar _bar;
}
```

I know that it is valid to use this class in the following context:

```
Bar bar;
{
    Foo foo;
    bar = foo.bar(); // bar is move-assigned, as foo is still in scope
}
```

Now, the situation I an wondering about is: what happens if I directly return bar from a method, without storing it beforehand:

```
Bar testFunc() {
    Foo foo;
    return foo.bar();
}

Bar test = testFunc();
// is test now valid?
```

I think that this should be theoretically fine, as `testFunc` returns a value that is constructed from the rvalue before `foo` is destroyed - but is this still the case if the compiler applies return-value-optimization?

I guess I am a little confused how exactly this works...

Comment: `return foo.bar()` is not valid criteria for RVO, so yes a copy from the rvalue will be made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is test now valid?

The code should be valid as long as the moved-from object is not accessed.

> but is this still the case if the compiler applies
>   return-value-optimization?

```
Bar testFunc() {
    Foo foo;          // Bar is constructed here
    return foo.bar(); // prvalue is move-constructed and copy elided
}
Bar test = testFunc(); // default ctor + move ctor (one copy elision)
```

In total one copy elision is performed.

Moving out a member seems like a code smell. It is hard to judge without knowing the concrete usage, but maybe:

```
Bar make_bar(const Foo& foo) {
    Bar bar;
    // init bar as needed
    return bar;
}
```

This way both calls will result in RVOs.

Comment: Okay, after reading on value categories in c++17 - changing the method to `Bar Foo::bar()` would return a prvalue and make the optimization possible? Or does the return statement in that method (which currently returns an xvalue) have to return a prvalue as well?

Comment: @Felix, I updated the answer. I was wrong: `testFunc()` will do RVO.